# React search engines

Tags: reactjs, graphql, search-engine

I searched the web for the top search engines that work with React. I found the followings:

- ElasticSearch
- InstantSearch

Now I want to know:

1. How these interact with the database(namely GraphQL/Prisma)?
2. What are the efficiencies of the above search engines. In particular if we can pre-process the data to improve efficiency, and how that would impact the parts that are truly dynamic, such as Blogs.
3. If any of the above works well with the CMS(Content Management System).

I would be so thankful in advance for your help on these.

Answer (score 1):

How Elastic Search queries:

1. Creates a static typed graphql schema from an elastic search mapping
2. Transforms your graphql query and creates an elastic search body
3. Runs the search on your elastic index
4. Returns the results and calls your hits schema

How instant search queries:

Instant search uses both server side rendering and has full routing capabilities. Server-side rendering (SSR) typically improves SEO and performance. When using SSR, your initial web content is generated on the server: browsers download pages with HTML content already in place.

Content Management Systems:

This is a more opinion based question but here’s what I can say, instant search seems to be the industry standard for creating cookie cutter CMS with react. For more on when you would use Elastic search read [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/building-enterprise-content-management-systems-on-elasticsearch)